# Find the limit of: $\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2})^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I strugle finding the $\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2})^{\sin(x)}$. 
I wanted to say that: let $1+t = \frac{x^2+2}{x^2}$, which gives me $x^2=\frac{2}{t}$ and there I don't know how to go any further. Until now, all the problems of that sort were of degree 1, and you could simply put $t$ in, play a bit with the exponentials and then get a solution. If it would be $\cos(x)$, I could say that $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$, but that's unfortunately not true for $\sin(x)$.

I then tried to say that $\sin(x)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$, which gives me after a few operations:
$\lim_{t\to0}(1+t)^{\sqrt{\cos^2(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t}}})})$, but I don't know how to continue, neither do I know whether it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Start with $y=\left(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2}\right)^{\sin x}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\ln y & = \sin x \ln\left(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2}\right)\\
& = \sin x \left[\ln (x^2+2) -2\ln(x)\right]\\
& = \sin x \left[\ln (x^2+2)\right] -2\sin x \left[\ln(x)\right].
\end{align*}
as $x \to 0$, the first term goes to $0$. So you now have to focus on the second term and write it as 
$$2\frac{\sin x}{x}x \ln (x).$$
Now use the fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. The other expression $x \ln x$ is easy to deal with using L'Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For small $x$, $\sin x \approx x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L =\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2}\right)^{\sin x}$. Then

\begin{align}
\ln L &= \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\sin x \ln\left(1+\frac2{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\cdot x\ln\left(1+\frac2{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \left(x\ln\left(1+\frac2{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac2{x^2}\right)}{\frac 1x}\\
\end{align}

L'Hospital from here gives $\ln L = 0\implies L = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

With *asymptotic analysis*, it's not so hard. First note it suffices to find the limit of the log. Then
$$\ln\Bigl(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2}\Bigr)^{\sin x}=\sin x\ln(x^2+2)-2\sin x \ln x$$
The first term tends to $0$. As to the second term, we know $\;\sin x\sim_0x$, hence
$$2\sin x\ln x\sim_0 2x\ln x\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0,$$
so that $\;\ln\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2+2}{x^2}\Bigr)^{\sin x}\!\!\!\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0 $ and finally
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2+2}{x^2}\Bigr)^{\sin x}=1.$$